# Regex: How to catch each line to create list

Tags: php, regex

My task is to convert one or more lists occurring in texts to a unordered  html list. The text I want to convert into a list item  starts with a line-break followed by a dash and a blank. But as my users were creative there might be line-breaks within a future list item as shown in the examples.

What regular expression could find the textblocks which are to be converted as lists. Just catching the first block and letting the conversion script run several times is also an option.

A "list" is defined by

1. two line-breaks
2. a dash
3. a blank
4. at least two lines of text
5. two line-breaks as the end of the list

The input text looks as follows:

```
Seit dem [Datum] ist Herr {Nachname} als Junior Designer bei Review für die Produktgruppen [Produktgruppen einfügen] zuständig.
In dieser Funktion umfasst sein Aufgabengebiet insbesondere die Kollektionsentwicklung:

- Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung

Weiterhin unterstützt Herr {Nachname} bei der Trendrecherche:

- Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings

Seit dem [Datum] ist Herr {Nachname} als Junior Designer bei Review für die Produktgruppen [Produktgruppen einfügen] zuständig.
In dieser Funktion umfasst sein Aufgabengebiet insbesondere die Kollektionsentwicklung:

- Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System
```

First try:

```
/((\n- .*)+)/g
```

crashes at the extra line-break in the first and second "list".

**What would be the correct regex, which regards everything between one dash and the next dash after a linebreak as one item to capture?** Catching all lines with dashes in one block would also be an option.

The expected output would ideally be either:
Group 1

```
- Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung
```

Group 2

```
- Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings
```

Group 3

```
- Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System
```

Alternatively each text seperately, which starts with return & a dash & a blank  with all text before the next dash occurs.

So e.g.

*Note:* Beware of nasty inline dashes within the text like here "einfügen: - schnitt- und"

In the end the code will run in php on a unix server, but might have to deal with Windows \r\n, but that adaption should be feasible. For simplicity I used \n for now.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I added the desired output options. Ideally I would get each "list block"  to convert them to a html list. But if I catch just one it is also fine, then I let the script run several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in MULTILINE mode to get 3 required matches:

```sh
(?:^-.*(?:\R(?:\h.*\R)*|\z))+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJZqjw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `^-`: Match `-` at the start
  - `.*`: Match everything till end of line
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `\R`: Match any line break
    - `(?:\h.*\R)*`: Match a whitespace and full line. Match 0 or more these sub-lines.
    - `|`: OR
    - `\z`: End of input
  - `)`: End non-capture group #2
- `)+`: non-capture group #1. Match 1+ of this group

Comment: php doesn't support multiline mode, but this gives me the the first block so I will just let the script run several times. Luckily it is a conversion, which will just  be done once in real live although over thousand of datasets.

Comment: PHP does support MULTILINE regex mode using `/m`

Comment: Ah true, you are correct it is the "g", which isn't supported!

Answer (score 1):

### List Individual Lines

**Regex**

```
/(?:(?:\n\n)(-.+?)(?=\n-)|\G\n(-.+?)(?=\n-|\n\n))/s
/                                               : Pattern delimiter
 (?:                                            : Open a non-capturing group
    \n\n                                        : Matches two line breaks (start of the list)
        (-.+?)                                  : Capture group; Matches a `-` followed by any character one or more times; non-greedy match
              (?=\n-)                           : Lookahead to check for a new line followed by a `-`; (note: you said that there was always at least two items)
                     |                          : OR operator
                      \G\n                      : Matches the end position of the last match, followed by a new line character
                          (-.+?)                : Capture group; matches a `-` followed by any character one or more times; non-greedy match
                                (?=\n-|\n\n)    : Lookahead to check for a new line followed by a `-`; or two new line characters (end of the list)
                                            )   : 
                                             /  : Pattern delimiter
                                              s : Modifier to make `.` match new lines
```

**Code Example**

```
$regex = '/(?:(?:\n\n)(-.+?)(?=\n-)|\G\n(-.+?)(?=\n-|\n\n))/s';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

- Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
            [1] => 
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
            [2] => 
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung
            [3] => 

- Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
            [4] => 
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
            [5] => 
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
            [6] => 
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings
            [7] => 

- Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
            [8] => 
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
            [9] => 
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => - Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => - Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => - Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => - Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
            [2] => - Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung
            [3] => 
            [4] => - Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
            [5] => - Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
            [6] => - Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings
            [7] => 
            [8] => - Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
            [9] => - Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System
        )
```

**Notes**

There are two capture groups `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`. Group 1 captures the first item in each list and the following items are captured in group 2.

So you access the individual items like:

```
Group 1 [0], Group 2 [1], Group 2 [2]

Group 1 [3], Group 2 [4], Group 2 [5], Group 2 [6]

Group 1 [7], Group 2 [8], Group 2 [9]
```

Which may sound complicated but can easily be turned into a simple list like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo "\n", ($matches[2][$i] ?: "\n\n" . $matches[1][$i]);
}

// OR...

#  foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $listItem) {
#      echo "\n", ($matches[2][$key] ?: "\n\n" . $listItem);
#  }


/* Outputs:

- Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung


- Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings


- Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System

*/
```

### List Groups

**Regex**

```
/\n\n(-.*?)(?=\n\n)/s
/                      : Pattern delimiter
 \n\n                  : Matches 2 new lines (start of list)
     (-.+?)            : Capture group; matches a `-` followed by any character 1 or more times; non-greedy match
           (?=\n\n)    : Lookahead: matches 2 new lines (end of list)
                   /   : Pattern delimiter
                    s  : Modifier to make `.` match new lines
```

**Code Example**

```
$regex = '/\n\n(-.*?)(?=\n\n)/s';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

- Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung


            [1] => 

- Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings


            [2] => 

- Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => - Mitarbeit bei der Erstellung des Kollektionsrahmenplans anhand der produktgruppenspezifischen Trends
- Umsetzung von Trends in marktgerechte (kommerzielle) Kollektionen anhand der Designbriefings
 [ggf. einfügen: - schnitt- und verarbeitungstechnische Betreuung der Produktgruppen]
- Teilnahme an Kreativworkshops und Designmeetings zur Kollektionsentwicklung
            [1] => - Beschaffung der aktuellsten Trendinformationen sowie deren optimale Umsetzung
- Analyse der abverkauften Kollektionen und vergangener Orderrunden
- Austausch mit den internen Beschaffungsbüros und dem Sourcing Buying hinsichtlich
  Verarbeitungs- und Materialtrends
- Durchführung spezifischer Trendrecherchen anhand der Konzeptbriefings
            [2] => - Erstellung von Konzept- und Kollektionsbriefings zum Season Kick Off
- Erstellung von aussagenfähigen, vollständigen und verständlichen Style Descriptions
- Datenanlage und -pflege im PDM-System
        )

)
```